# Finding $\int -2\arcsin(4x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone point out my mistake? I can't seem to spot what I did wrong.

Here's my work, using integration by parts with these variables: $u = \arcsin(4x)$, $du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$, $dv = dx$, and $v = x$.

$$\int -2\arcsin(4x)dx = -2(\arcsin(4x) - \int[\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx])$$
Using substitution to find the second term, I arrive at:
$$=-2(x\arcsin(4x)+\sqrt{1-x^2})+C$$

Comment: Is the derivative of $\arcsin (4x)$ really $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

Comment: Oh, that was quick. Yeah, I didn't really think that through hard enough, huh?

Answer (score 1):

$$I=-2\int \sin^{-1} (4x) dx$$ Integrate it by parts treating $\sin^{-1} x$ 1 as tyhe first function.
$$I=-2\left(x\sin^{-1} (4x) -\int \frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-16x^2}}dx\right)$$
$$I=-2\left(x\sin^{-1} (4x) +\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}\right), t=1-16x^2.$$
$$I=-2x\sin^{-1} (4x) -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-16x^2}+C$$